# Mudança de cor no grafico de barras empilhadas

Tags: r, funções, gráfico

queria saber se é possível mudar as cores das barras no gráfico de barras empilhadas. o meu já fica com as cores do próprio R, e eu gostaria de colocar em tons de azul. alguém saberia me dizer como posso fazer isso?

```
#Grafico de barras empilhadas dos municipios e usa camisinha
Base |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = municipio, fill = uso_camisinha ))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill")+
  labs( x = "Município",y = "%", fill = "Usa camisinha")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales :: percent_format())
  theme_light()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim é possível modificar as cores das barras no gráfico de barras empilhadas.

Você pode utilizar as escalas de cores [ColorBrewer](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html) que vem embutidas no ggplot2 e fornecem esquemas de cores sequenciais, divergentes e qualitativos. No caso de gráfico de barras empilhadas ajuste o esquema de preenchimento de cores com [`scale_fill_brewer()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html#ref-usage) junto de uma das [paletas pré-definas](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html#palettes):

```
library(ggplot2)
 
cidades <- c(rep("Salvador" , 3) , rep("São Paulo" , 3) , rep("Belo Horizonte" , 3))
frequencia <- rep(c("Raramente" , "Ocasionalmente" , "Sempre") , 3)
entrevistados <- abs(rnorm(9 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(cidades, frequencia, entrevistados)
data$frequencia<- factor(data$frequencia, levels = c("Raramente", "Ocasionalmente", "Sempre")) # Sugestão feia nos comentários pelo usuário @RuiBarradas.
 
data |>
ggplot(aes(fill=frequencia, y=entrevistados, x=cidades)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
    labs( x = "Município",y = "%", fill = "Usa camisinha") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales :: percent_format()) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

[image: Gráfico de barras empilhada usando paleta builtin Blues]

Outra possibilidade é configurar manualmente assim personalizando o esquema de cores de preenchimento da escala com [`scale_fill_manual()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html#ref-usage):

```
#Utilizando o mesmo dataframe do exemplo anterior.
data |>
ggplot(aes(fill=frequencia, y=entrevistados, x=cidades)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
    labs( x = "Município",y = "%", fill = "Usa camisinha") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales :: percent_format()) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#33DAFF", "#33AFFF", "#3386FF"))
```

[image: Gráfico de barras empilhada usando paleta personalizada]

Comment: Votei para cima mas a legenda está errada, `Raramente` é menos vezes que `Ocasionalmente`. Isso deve ser mudado com `data$frequencia<- factor(data$frequencia, levels = c("Raramente", "Ocasionalmente", "Sempre"))` antes do plot.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, feita a correção e mais uma vez muito obrigado por me orientar.